# Add parameters to a request for Fans/Likers of a Facebook Page

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

So what I've been able to put together so far is that if you have the unique FBID to supply the following link with, you're able to get up to ~10,000 unique users who have "Liked" that page:

https://www.facebook.com/search/{Facebook ID}/likers?ref=about

Is there any way to append additional parameters to that link? Such as, people who like this page, and this other page {separate ID}? Or, people who like this page, and also lived in this city {city ID}?

The above link doesn't seem to "play nice" with other elements added into the Graph search, or maybe I'm not understanding how Graph functions. If I add things in to the search bar, it "kills" the page as a parameter. Facebook searching has become mysterious to me in the past couple of years.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? you are not allowed to scrape that page anyway, and you are not allowed to do anything with that data - not even to store it. so what is the use case?

Comment: Oh really? It's for an ARG - one of those online "scavenger hunt" type games - and I guess this is a part of the puzzle. No commercial or monetary incentive, at least on my part! Also, searches like this used to be really commonplace, and figuring out how the new system works is a fun experiment.

Comment: what do you want to do with the list of fans? how exactly does that work?

Comment: Use the API and not www.facebook.com. The API you find under graph.facebook.com and you can read about it on https://developers.facebook.com/docs